# Need a dataset with more labels (output cardinality) than features (input cardinality)

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, bigdata, multilabel-classification

For a classification or regression problem, if

'X' is the input Matrix of size m X n
and
'Y' is the expected output/ labels Matrix of size m X k.

Then I need a dataset where k >= n. 
(If also possible 'Y' should be a high density labels)

That is where the number of labels/ output exceeds the input feature space.
Can you suggest me one such dataset.

Regards,

Comment: Why do you need such a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://mulan.sourceforge.net/datasets-mlc.html) is a lot of multi-labeled datasets, one of which has 500 nominal attributes and 983 labels.
You can also take other datasets and drop some features (randomly or by feature selection) so that their count became less than labels.

Answer (score 0):

There are many such datasets on [LIBSVM Data](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/).
It contains many classification, regression, multi-label and string data sets. Many are from UCI, Statlog, StatLib and other collections.